# Unset salesforce Picklist values

Tags: php, soap, salesforce

I am developing an application with salesforce with SOAP Api.I have a problem with Picklist values.
I update values in salesforce in the format of

```
$object->field_name="val1;val2;val3";
```

Its working,But when i pass

```
     $object->field_name="";
```

The value does not changes,Anyone know how to unset values in salesforce using php soap.

Comment: Maybe it was the failed, when updating with empty value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the field name in the [`fieldsToNull`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_concepts_core_data_objects.htm#sobject_topic) array on the object. In your example, you'd do that like this:

```
$object->fieldsToNull = array("field_name");
```

For more info, see the [PHP Toolkit 20.0 FieldsToNull Sample](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_FieldsToNull_Sample_%28Partner%29) from the docs.